# PySpark won't convert timestamp

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, simpledateformat

I have a very simple CSV, call it `test.csv`

```
name,timestamp,action
A,2012-10-12 00:30:00.0000000,1
B,2012-10-12 01:00:00.0000000,2 
C,2012-10-12 01:30:00.0000000,2 
D,2012-10-12 02:00:00.0000000,3 
E,2012-10-12 02:30:00.0000000,1
```

I'm trying to read it using pyspark and add a new column indicating the month.

First I read in the data, and everything looks ok.

```
df = spark.read.csv('test.csv', inferSchema=True, header=True)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- action: double (nullable = true)

+----+-------------------+------+
|name|          timestamp|action|
+----+-------------------+------+
|   A|2012-10-12 00:30:00|   1.0|
|   B|2012-10-12 01:00:00|   2.0|
|   C|2012-10-12 01:30:00|   2.0|
|   D|2012-10-12 02:00:00|   3.0|
|   E|2012-10-12 02:30:00|   1.0|
+----+-------------------+------+
```

But when I try to add my column, the formatting option doesn't seem to do anything.

```
df.withColumn('month', to_date(col('timestamp'), format='MMM')).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------------+------+----------+
|name|          timestamp|action|     month|
+----+-------------------+------+----------+
|   A|2012-10-12 00:30:00|   1.0|2012-10-12|
|   B|2012-10-12 01:00:00|   2.0|2012-10-12|
|   C|2012-10-12 01:30:00|   2.0|2012-10-12|
|   D|2012-10-12 02:00:00|   3.0|2012-10-12|
|   E|2012-10-12 02:30:00|   1.0|2012-10-12|
+----+-------------------+------+----------+
```

What's going on here?

Comment: what do you want to convert it to? month?

Comment: Yes. According to the documentation on the Oracle page, MMM should accomplish that, but no format i've tried as any effect. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: there is a inbuilt function called month https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

Comment: @RameshMaharjan That's very useful, I didn't know functions like that existed! However, you'll appreciate that this was a simplified example, and I would still like to get custom formatting working, or understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: what you are doing is column based transformations and there is to_date function as well in the above link which doesn't take format parameter. thus its not working for you . I guess what you are looking for is udf functions.

Comment: The documentation for PySpark shows a format parameter https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_date` with `format` is used for parse string type columns. What you need is `date_format`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df.withColumn('month', date_format(col('timestamp'), format='MMM')).show()

# +----+-------------------+------+-----+
# |name|          timestamp|action|month|
# +----+-------------------+------+-----+
# |   A|2012-10-12 00:30:00|   1.0|  Oct|
# |   B|2012-10-12 01:00:00|   2.0|  Oct|
# |   C|2012-10-12 01:30:00|   2.0|  Oct|
# |   D|2012-10-12 02:00:00|   3.0|  Oct|
# |   E|2012-10-12 02:30:00|   1.0|  Oct|
# +----+-------------------+------+-----+
```